# NonProxyHost Configuration issue in weblogic giving error

Tags: java, service, proxy, weblogic

I am configuring http and https both for proxy and nonproxyHosts, but I am getting error for host mentioned after the delimiter saying is not recognized as an internal or external command.
ex:- sysprop = %sysprop% -Dhttps.proxyhost = abc.com -Dhttps.proxyport=8500 -Dhttps.nonproxyhosts = host1.com | host2.com .
here getting error saying host2.com is not recognized as internal or external command.

Comment: First, remove spaces in the property value.

Comment: I just typed here, actually there are no spaces..

Answer (score 0):

Write the nonProxyHost between quotation marks

```
-Dhttps.nonproxyhosts="host1.com|host2.com"
```

The pipe | symbol is used to pipe output from one command into another (therefore you are trying to pipe everything from before the pipe into the non existent host2.com program). See https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true